# Can "si vixero" be understood in the sense of "quamdiu vixero" in Petrarch, Fam. 11.6?

Tags: idiom, renaissance-latin

In Petrarch's *Epistolae ad Familiares* [11.6](http://www.bibliotecaitaliana.it/testo/bibit000255), we find this sentence about friendship as both joy and burden:

Etsi enim amicorum nichil affectu ac pietate dulcius habeam aut sperem, sepe tamen arctius me diligi quam otio meo expediat, questus sum querarque si vixero.

Elaine Fantham (I Tatti 76) translates this passage as follows:

"Though I have or hope for nothing sweeter than the affection and loyalty of friends, I have often complained of being loved more closely than suits my leisure, and will go on complaining if I live."

Certainly, "if I live" is a straightforward enough interpretation of *si vixero*, but to my ears, it implies that Petrarch is thinking about a definite event or point in time. In the immediate context there isn't anything in particular that would serve this role. So, I am wondering if this construction can sustain a more open-ended interpretation: "I will keep complaining for as long as I live." The similar phrase *quamdiu vixero* has exactly this meaning of "for however long I end up having lived."

On the other hand, in the more remote context, Petrarch talks about things that can go wrong while one is traveling, as he is currently traveling, and as his addressee is considering doing. So, perhaps this passage is best understood as gesturing obliquely to his journey and its attendant perils: *si vixero* as "if I end up surviving this journey."

Comment: I am not an expert in this, but your last thought seems attractive to me, given the context.  In other words, he might be using *si vixero* to mean "if I survive," especially because of his use of the future perfect.